# Shard Status Command - Discord.JS V12

Tags: discord, discord.js

How can I fetch all of the shards status to check if they are online or offline through a single command, within a shard itself.

How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

According to [discordjs.guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/faq.html) :

> A specific shards heartbeat can be found on the WebSocketShard instance, accessible at `<client>.ws.shards > .ping`.

Which means you could check every shard's heartbeat, and make check if the value is not "too high" to find out whether or not the shard is online.